# UIToolbar Shifts Down Weird?

Tags: objective-c, autolayout, uistoryboard, uitoolbar, nslayoutconstraint

I don't know if any of you have experienced this but in my application I have a tableview and when you press on a cell it will take you to a UIWebview and the web view will load a link, however when I perform my segue from the tableview to what I guess you could call the detail view the toolbar on the detail page (used to control the web view) appears not on the bottom of the view for an instant and then snaps to the bottom, not a huge problem but it's just not smooth, any suggestions? Could this be a auto-layout/constraint problem?

See the images below (look at the toolbar):

Right when I press the tableView: 
[image]

A millisecond after once the view fully loads: 
[image]

Notice the toolbar.

Weird. Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try running this situation on different screen sized simulators. Does the tool bar on all screen sizes snaps from top to bottom?

Comment: yes it does @somexyz